issue with update manager in Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS after installing python 3.11.2
Hit:1 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease
Hit:2 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:3 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Hit:5 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Hit:6 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/cnf-update-db", line 3, in 
import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'
Reading package lists... Done
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if /usr/bin/test -w /var/lib/command-not-found/ -a -e /usr/lib/cnf-update-db; then /usr/lib/cnf-update-db > /dev/null; fi'
E: Sub-process returned an error code

Try changing the python version. If it does not work, you will have to reinstall. Never change the default python version. Instead, use virtual environments
